# VBA-Powerpoint Is the position of shapes in groups mistaken?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I create a group with shape "A" (let's say a rectangle) and shape "B".
It happens that bot A.Left\Top and B.Left\Top are equal to Group.Left\top.

It correctly happens that A.Name = "A", B.Name = "B", Group.Name = "GroupName".

The bahavior is very strange. I would even say that back to 1 month ago, it did not behave like that.
I realised because I used a macro that stopped working, and that was the only possible reason. Notice: I do not even know how to solve that! It seems to me that it is impossible to get left,top of a grouped shape O.o

Any clue?

Tnx

Comment: Please post the code you used to determine that, so we can be sure we're all on the same page when trying to replicate this

Comment: We would like to be mind code readers, but we are not...

Comment: A group has a `GroupItems` collection, and each individual shape in that collection has its own separate Top/Left properties